# Targeting paragraph inside a div

Tags: css, class, html, paragraph

I have this line of HTML code:

```
<div id="slideshow2">
  <div class="active2">
    <img src="noangel.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">NoAngel</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="anders.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">This is Anders</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="fayeblais.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">Something about FayeBlais</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="ronny.png" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">Ronny Information</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I target the first paragraph only or the 3rd one only to change the color, font type etc ?

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To select only the first paragraph in the third `<div>`:

```css
#slideshow2 > div:nth-of-type(3) > p {
   /* Styles */
}
```

That selector selects an element that has the ID of `slideshow2`, then the third `<div>` that is a direct child, and finally the `<p>` element which is a direct child of that `<div>`.

Here's a demonstration:

```css
#slideshow2 > div:nth-of-type(3) > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow2">
  <div class="active2">
    <img src="noangel.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">NoAngel</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="anders.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">This is Anders</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="fayeblais.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">Something about FayeBlais</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="ronny.png" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    <p class="imgDescription2">Ronny Information</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yBVY/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using nth-child css selector.

for your case, try this to target 3rd paragraph inside slideshow2 div.

`#slideshow2 p:nth-child(3) {color:blue; font-size:20px;}`

You can find more tricks to target elements of your choice or nth childs here: http://nthmaster.com/

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

for the first p only

```
p:nth-child(1) { }
```

3rd

```
p:nth-child(3) { }
```

... get it?

Comment: This won't work, I don't know how it is voted up and that too in mere 30 seconds

Comment: hmm, yep, this isn't working, i've wrote the basic usage of nth-child selectors without testing it. My bad. This will works only if it was something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6C7e/4/

Answer (score 0):

first, select 3rd div with syntax like: 
  `div:nth-of-type(3){ }` 
/* and  this means you are selecting everything inside 3rd div. */

how ever, if you wish to select 2rd p  of 3rd div even you don't have 2rd p in your question.  you will do syntax like this :

`div:nth-of-type(3)>p:nth-of-type(2) { }`

get it?